# Is there a lot of overhead (IO/Storage) for Barman if I rename a database in my postgres instance?

Tags: postgresql, barman, rename

Barman backs up the whole instance, so I would think that renaming one of the databases in an instance is simply an alter script:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE old_database_name RENAME TO new_database_name;
```

... that Barman picks up as part of reading our WAL. Thus no real overhead in terms of IO and temporary space usage.

Is this correct? Our backup server doesn't have a lot of space left and is pressed on IO as it is.

(I'm thinking worst case would be that it copied over ALL of the data during backup.)